# Using GSON JsonParser on a String with a space

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm completely blanking out here - there's no convenience method to work with spaces when parsing in gson? I'm getting the following exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: 
Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 5 path $
```

This is my code:

```
jsonArray.add(new JsonParser().parse(id));
```

where id is a String with a space, for example `Hello World`

Comment: But, Hello World isn't valid JSON is it? Shouldn't it be something like { "Hello World" } or { "Something" : "Hello World" }

Comment: doh... I think it's time to call it a day

Comment: Ok, I'll post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello World isn't valid JSON is it? Shouldn't it be something like { "Hello World" } or { "Something" : "Hello World" }

Comment: Thanks again, ended up using JsonPrimitive instead of a parser. Worked like a charm!